# What version of Visual Studio is msbuild 14.0 part of?

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I need MSBUILD 14.0 and am willing to install Visual Studio to get it.
What version of Visual Studio do I need to install to get MSBUILD 14.0?
It looks like the MSBUILD version number and the Visual Studio name do not match.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting in Visual Studio 2013, the MSBuild Toolset version is the same as the Visual Studio version number. So if you have Visual Studio 2015 you should have MSBuild 14.0 already on your system.

Comment: Too bad the Visual Studio version number doesn't more directly correspond to the MSBuild version number.

Comment: @Solx Wikipedia has a Visual Studio release version number table. Google can easily take you there.

Comment: I just noticed that in Visual Studio, if you do Help -> About, that is has information about 'Version' and it shows the MSBuild version number